# TypeScript Error TS2322: Type 'Option' is not assignable to type '(string & Option) | (number & Option) | (readonly string[] & Option)'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to load a simple `Listbox` component from `@headlessui/react`.

## Select.tsx

```
type Option = {
    id: number
    name: string
}

interface IProps {
    label?: string
    options: Array<Option>
}

export const Select = ({ label, options }: IProps) => {
    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = React.useState<Option>(options[0])

    return (
        <Listbox value={selectedOption} onChange={setSelectedOption}>
            <Listbox.Label>{label}: </Listbox.Label>
            <Listbox.Button>{selectedOption.name}</Listbox.Button>
            <Listbox.Options>
                {options.map((option) => (
                    <Listbox.Option key={option.id} value={option}>
                        {option.name}
                    </Listbox.Option>
                ))}
            </Listbox.Options>
        </Listbox>
    )
}
```

I get this error (red-squiggly line) on `value` of `value={option}`:

> TS2322: Type 'Option' is not assignable to type '(string & Option) | (number & Option) | (readonly string[] & Option)'.
> Type 'Option' is not assignable to type 'readonly string[] & Option'.
> Type 'Option' is missing the following properties from type 'readonly string[]': length, concat, join, slice, and 16 more.

I even tried doing `value={option.name}` but then the select element gets removed from DOM after I select it for the first time.

## App.tsx

```
const shapes = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Circle',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Square',
    },
]

<Select label="Shape" options={shapes} />
```

How should I solve this one?

Comment: FWIW, I just created a fresh React project (`npx create-react-app projectname --template typescript`), added `@headlessui/react` to it, and copied and pasted the [`Listbox` example](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui/blob/develop/packages/%40headlessui-react/README.md#listbox-select) verbatim into `App.tsx`. I get exactly the same error you get. Looks like a problem in the type information for the lib. You may want to raise [an issue](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui/issues).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder cool thanks...i already had opened it but thought it was because I was using it in Chrome Extension but now I've updated the title https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui/issues/187

Comment: The issue you originally raised was about something completely different. I recommend you raise a *new* issue about this problem and delete those comments from the closed issue.

Comment: Please share minimum reproducable example

Comment: @T.J.Crowder turns out the issue I originally raised was about other library so I mentioned in the comments what the issue is. now if they close this one, then i'll open another one.

Comment: @captain-yossarian the funny thing is it works perfectly fine in Codesandbox → https://codesandbox.io/s/headlessuireact-listbox-example-forked-lbct7?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is in the library itself.

And the solution is to use `@dev` version for now like `npm install @headlessui/react@dev`

Hopefully it will soon get fixed & released so we don't need to use `@dev` flag.